# Angular 2 ngFor gets undefined when accessing a property

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am follwing `angular2` tutorials and tries to iterate over `Array`:

```
<table class = "table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Descreption</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor = "#v of videos"></tr>
        <td>{{v.id}}</td>
        <td>{{v.title}}</td>
        <td>{{v.desc}}</td>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

The error I get is `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`, but when I print the object in the **same** html :

```
<!--printing the same object -->
{{videos[0] | json}}
```

It shows the object as expected, for example:

```
{ "id": 1, "title": "title..", "videoCode": "afe6JW2oTZc", "desc": "My Videos" }
```

I have tried `json` pipe - `{{v.id | json}}`, and still it does not work,

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've been following the wrong tutorials. The usage of `#v` is a very old syntax, and hasn't been used since it went to beta. The new syntax uses the `let` keyword:

On the other hand, you should place your `td` inside the `tr` loop, and not outside of it:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Descreption</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let v of videos">
           <td>{{v.id}}</td>
           <td>{{v.title}}</td>
           <td>{{v.desc}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Probably the second thing I said is your issue here, but I believe the bigger issue is you using an old version of angular. Just head over to [angular.io](https://angular.io) and take the tutorials there

Comment: Yes the tr tag was misplaced.

Comment: And I am new to angular 2 so I will look for after beta tutorials.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas look for release tutorials. lots have changed. You are safest looking at the angular.io website, or look for tutorials >= RC.5. Because in RC.5 they introduced `NgModule`

Comment: Thanks, will start from there.

Answer (score 3):

**`#`** has been replaced by **`let`** keyworkd.
If you are dealing with **async** call then you need to use `?.` operator for lazy binding of properties as shown below,

```
<tbody>                        
        <tr *ngFor = "let v of videos">
         <td>{{v?.id}}</td>
         <td>{{v?.title}}</td>
         <td>{{v?.desc}}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

**OR**

you can use **`*ngIf`** until data gets loaded to object as shown below,

```
 <table class = "table table-hover" *ngIf="videos">   //<<<===here
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Descreption</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor = "let v of videos">
         <td>{{v.id}}</td>
         <td>{{v.title}}</td>
         <td>{{v.desc}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: psst, this will still crash, because `v` will always be undefined, even if `videos` have been loaded. bad positioning of tr/td :)